# What is meant by this SystemVerilog typedef enum statement?

Tags: system-verilog, hdl

```
typedef enum logic [1:0] {S0, S1, S2} statetype;
```

Does this statement mean that any variable declared as '`statetype`' can only take three values, 2'b00, 2'b01, and 2'b10? If so, what happens if I assign the said variable with the value 2'b11?

Answer (score 0):

The IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 6.19.3 *Type checking*, states:

> Enumerated types are strongly typed; thus, a variable of type enum
> cannot be directly assigned a value that lies outside the enumeration
> set unless an explicit cast is used or unless the enum variable is a
> member of a union. This is a powerful type-checking aid, which
> prevents users from accidentally assigning nonexistent values to
> variables of an enumerated type. The enumeration values can still be
> used as constants in expressions, and the results can be assigned to
> any variable of a compatible integral type.
>
> Enumerated variables are type-checked in assignments, arguments, and
> relational operators.

What I observe in practice is that some simulators issue a compile warning while others issue a compile error.  You can see what happens on multiple simulators on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/K9ez) (if you sign up for a free account there).

For example, with VCS, the following code:

```
module tb;

typedef enum logic [1:0] {S0, S1, S2} statetype;

statetype s;

initial begin
    s = S0;
    $display("n=%s,s=%0d,", s.name(), s);
    s = 3;
    $display("n=%s,s=%0d,", s.name(), s);
end

endmodule
```

issues this warning:

```
Warning-[ENUMASSIGN] Illegal assignment to enum variable
tb.v, 16
tb, "s = 3;"
  Only expressions of the enum type can be assigned to an enum variable. 
  The type int is incompatible with the enum 'statetype'
  Expression: 3
  Use the static cast operator to convert the expression to enum type.
```

but, it still runs the simulation and prints:

```
n=S0,s=0
n=,s=3
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question should be rephrased to say that what is this is happening in our test-bench and how to avoid it. This will gives us more cleaner and bug free code.

efficient code to avoid the confusion:

```
typedef enum logic [1:0] {S0, S1, S2} statetype;

module top();

  statetype st_e;
  
  initial begin
    for(int val=0;val<4; val++) begin
      // casting for avoid confusion and gotchas
      if (!$cast(st_e,val)) begin
        $error("Casting not possible -> statetype:%0s and val:%0d",st_e,val);
      end else begin
        $display("statetype:%0s and val:%0d",st_e,val);
      end
    end
  end
  
endmodule: top
```

This code is already there in  [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/fu_V) feel free to try it and update it. This could be replace with the sv macro for more efficiency. Please let me know I will provide the example for macros.

Output will be:

```
# run -all
# statetype:S0 and val:0
# statetype:S1 and val:1
# statetype:S2 and val:2
# ** Error: Casting not possible -> statetype:S2 and val:3
#    Time: 0 ns  Scope: top File: testbench.sv Line: 14
# exit
```